# Bootstrap - Place banner outside main container.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have worked with a website in a few months and now come to an issue where the client wants an ad "outside" the main container and i use Bootstrap standard grid.

Because the page is centered and responsive, I can not get the ad to lie on the left side because i already use 16 columns.

Do you have any ideas on how I can succeed?

Please see the image
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6b7Tn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great if you can provide some code. But one way to move an element relative to where it is currently us to use CSS `transform: translate();`. If your banner is on the right side of the container, and you want to push it outside of the container, apply `transform: translateX(100%);` to the banner element, and that will move it to the right by 100% of the width of the banner relative to where it is currently. Here's a demo http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/jyPGrM

Comment: Million thanks Michel, transform: translateX(100%); was new to me. It worked out perfectly. Now I have saved a little hair on my head, thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it only for big screens.

I used position absolute together with col class for image responsivnes, and i hide it for smaller devices because they will not work.

This is my code

```
<div class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md" id="side-bar">
    <p>Our Partners</p>
    <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />
    <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img img-responsive" />
</div>
```